# Anychart - RangeSplineArea Lowstroke with markers

Tags: anychart

I came across a little problem. I once created an Anychart and set markers for the HighStroke and the LowStroke.

However in Anychart 7.14 I can only aktivate markers for the HighStroke
with

```
series.markers().enabled(true);
```

[Now - Just HighStroke with markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw5GP.jpg)

[Past - LowStroke and HighStroke with markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQYaT.jpg)

How can I enable them?

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

```
series.markers(true);
```

always sets markers to high stroke of any range chart. 
Could you clarify what are the challenges that need to be met with lowStroke markers? Probably we may suggest you better solution. 
Thanks for your question!

Comment: Its just for the looks. The RangeSplineArea in my case, is a temperature Area where there is a lowest temperature und a highest one. If there are temperature changes in the lowstroke, it would be easier to recognize with markers.

Comment: Ok, I see!  In this case I may suggest you the next solution - https://jsfiddle.net/wf4hjn9g/1/ .   Also you are able to adjust appearance of lowStroke markers. I hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you! That is a way to go. I also thought about making a RangeSplineArea without strokes and create 2 line charts for low and high instead.